# Display an array of dates in table view, Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, tableview, nsdictionary

After searching SO, I found that there are many questions on grouping and displaying data in table view controller but none requiring order by date.

I have an array of date objects

```
let dateObjects = [2016-12-22 16:00:00 +0000, 2016-12-22 16:15:00 +0000, 2016-12-23 16:00:00 +0000, 2016-12-23 16:15:00 +0000, 2016-12-23 16:30:00 +0000, 2016-12-24 16:00:00 +0000]
```

**How can I create an array like the below from the above dateObjects.**

```
let items = [["4:00 pm", "4:15 pm"], ["4:00 pm", "4:15 pm", "4:30 pm"], ["4:00 pm"]]
```

I want dates to be grouped and shown in a table view like the below picture. Note that the dates and times are in ascending order.

I've tried to group the dates in a dictionary to realise that the dictionaries are not ordered and therefore I would not get the order I want.

[image: Appointments]

This code works when I supply an array of items. **But how can I create an array like items from date objects ?**

```
let section = ["Thu, 22 Dec", "Fri, 23 Dec", "Sat, 24 Dec"]

let items = [["4:00 pm", "4:15 pm"], ["4:00 pm", "4:15 pm", "4:30 pm"], ["4:00 pm"]]


override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return self.section.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.items[section].count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.disclosureIndicator
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return self.section[section]
}


var valueToPass:String!
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    // Get Cell Label
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as UITableViewCell

    valueToPass = currentCell.textLabel?.text
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "TableDetailSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: If you want ordered dates you need to create an **array** which contains the dates and the times in a subarray respectively. The array represents the sections and the subarrays the *times* in the sections. The most suitable way is a custom struct or class including properties to format the dates to the proper strings. `NSDictionary` is not recommended anyway.

Comment: I can't help noticing you didn't show _any_ code. None. Zero. Zilch. Nada. So how can anyone say what you're doing wrong when you don't show what you're doing at all?

Comment: do you mean something like this ? `['Thu 22 Dec' : ['4:00 pm', '4:15 pm'], 'Fri 23 Dec': ['4:00 pm', '4:15 pm', '4: 30 pm'], 'Sat 24 Dec' : ['4:00 pm']]`

Comment: @matt, Added my code.

Comment: Not sure why its being down voted..

Comment: Okay, your code looks fine. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what the question is. You said:

> I want dates to be grouped and shown in a table view like the below picture. Note that the dates and times are in ascending order.
>
> I've tried to group the dates in a dictionary to realise that the dictionaries are not ordered and therefore I would not get the order I want.

Okay, but then you showed your code, and there are *no dictionaries* anywhere to be seen! Instead, you have an array and an array of arrays. That looks like it should work. And sure enough, I copied your code into a project and ran it, and this is what I got:

[image]

Well, that looks pretty much like what you said you wanted. (Except for the heights of things; you didn't give that part of your code. But it's the right data grouped correctly and in the right order.) So it seems to me that you have code that gives the desired result. Therefore it's hard to see what your question is about.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but the real problem is I am having difficulty in creating an array like this (from an array of date objects)  `let items = [["4:00 pm", "4:15 pm"], ["4:00 pm", "4:15 pm", "4:30 pm"], ["4:00 pm"]]`

Comment: If that is "the real problem" then ask about that. But it isn't what you asked. I cannot read your mind! I answered the question you did ask. Show the input and desired output. That's why I downvoted the question - it was a very badly framed question.